# NumPy array data Comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two 3D Numpy array

```
win_combination = np.array([
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]],
[[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]],
[[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]],
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]],
[[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1]],
[[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]],
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]],
[[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
])
```

and,

```
game_log = np.array([[1 1],[0 2],[1 0]])
```

I would like to compare if the game_log data matches any of the arrays in win_combination if it matches it may print True else print False.

Basically I want that if game_log == [[0, 0],[0, 1],[0, 2]] it may print True if it isn't then my code should compare another array game_log == [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]] if not then #another and so on till last and print false if there is no array that matches game_log and in this case it should print False

I have tried,

```
for comb in win_combination:
    if game_log == comb:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What is your actual question?

Comment: You don't have two 3D arrays. You have a 2D and a 3D

Comment: Unindent the `else`. You don't necessarily want to return `False` if the first element is not matching.

Answer (score 1):

Two arrays are equal if `np.all(x == y)` (or alternatively `(x == y).all()`). You have a 3D array of shape `(N, A, B)` and a 2D array of shape `(A, B)`. In this case, `N=8`, `A=3` and `B=2`. These shapes broadcast to the shape of the 3D array. If you apply [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to the last two dimensions, you can get `N` `True` or `False` values for each of the combinations. [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) will then tell you if any of them are `True`.

`all` has an `axis` keyword. As of numpy 1.7.0, `axis` can specify more than one axis simultaneously, so you can do:

```
matches = np.all(win_combination == game_log, axis=(-1, -2))
```

For older versions of numpy, you would have to reshape to get a single axis, or apply `all` twice:

```
matches = np.all((win_combination == game_log).reshape(win_comination.shape[0], -1), axis=-1)
```

OR

```
matches = np.all(np.all(win_combination == game_log, axis=-1), axis=-1)
```

The final result is `matches.any()` or `np.any(matches)`. You can write it as a one-liner:

```
np.all(win_combination == game_log, axis=(-1, -2)).any()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
ans = np.any(np.all(game_log == win_combination, axis=(1,2)))
print(ans)
```

Comment: You don't need to replicate `game_log`: broadcasting does it for you since the dimensions line up on the right. You don't need size either. Your entire solution is just the third line, but with `game_log` instead of `games`.

Comment: Here's a link you may find interesting: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html. It's what makes so much of the magic in numpy possible.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm not that good with broadcasting, maybe this link helps me @MadPhysicist

Comment: Here's another one that helped me visualize it better: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/theory.broadcasting.html. It's not a simple subject, but you get used to it after a while. The basic idea is to line up the shapes on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
   def in_array(game_log, array):
        for comb in array:
            for arr in comb:
                if game_log.all() == arr.all():
                    return True
        return False
```

Pass the **game_log** to the first argument and the 3D to the next one, based on what i understand it should print **True** if the combination is in the array and **False** otherwise.

Keep in mind that the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. So its best to use **all()** if both arrays are exact matches and **any()** if any element in one array exists in the other.

Comment: You should really return values instead of printing them. You can always print a return value, but you can't recover what you've printed without returning it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing